# How to implement MATCH() AGAINST() function using `FunctionContributor`?

Tags: hibernate

I can implement simple functions like `ST_Y(?)` or `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(?,?)` like this:

```
class StYFunction extends StandardSQLFunction {

    private static final BasicTypeReference<Double> RETURN_TYPE = new BasicTypeReference<Double>("double", double.class, SqlTypes.DOUBLE);

    public StYFunction(String name) {
        super(name, true, RETURN_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SqlAppender sqlAppender, List<? extends SqlAstNode> sqlAstArguments, ReturnableType<?> returnType, SqlAstTranslator<?> translator) {
        if (sqlAstArguments.size() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Function " + getName() + " requires exactly 1 argument");
        }
        sqlAppender.append("ST_Y(");
        sqlAstArguments.get(0).accept(translator);
        sqlAppender.append(")");
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering how to implement `MATCH(?) AGAINST(?)` function. In a simple case, `MATCH(?,?)` should work.

But in some cases, This function is written like:

```
MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

or

```
MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```